# Access Ubuntu SSH Server from Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: 12.04, server, ssh

Hi I have a Ubuntu Server and I have configured public and private key on that server. Previously I was using Windows 7. So I just installed Putty and was accessing my Ubuntu Server from Windows 7 successfully.

Now I migrated from Windows 7 to Ubuntu 12.04. Now I want to access my Ubuntu Server. 
How can I do it? Will I have to use Putty? Or something else will also work?

I remember when I used to access Ubuntu Server from Windows 7 via Putty I had to provide a key over there as well. So How can I do this now?

I installed putty as well. But its not working. Every time I start putty, after some seconds a message is displayed "Server unexpectedly closed the connection".

Comment: You don't need putty. Ubuntu comes with `ssh` command. You can use it with with no changes if password based login is not disabled in the server.

Comment: How can I use ssh to remotely access ubuntu server? And Where I will be providing passphrase for key, which i used to do in putty?

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/ConnectingTo for how to connect from Ubuntu desktop client. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys for how to generate the key and send the public key to your server. You will need a new pair of keys. If you set a pass-phrase with your key, ssh will prompt you for it in the terminal.

Comment: I am new to ubuntu therefore I am unable to understand. I have the private key which was generated on server. Where I will have to put this key? I have passphrase for key as well. Where I will have to put it as well?

Comment: Can you ssh into the server without the private/public keys from Ubuntu desktop?

Answer (score 0):

ssh (package openssh-client) is a standard part of Ubuntu.

You may need to convert your private key from putty format for use with Linux ssh.

See: [How do I install a ssh private key generated by puttygen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15378/how-do-i-install-a-ssh-private-key-generated-by-puttygen)

Comment: I am new to ubuntu therefore I am unable to understand. I have the private key which was generated on server. Where I will have to put this key? I have passphrase for key as well. Where I will have to put it as well?

Comment: @JamilShehzad Your pritave/public key pair should have been generated in Windows 7 using puttygen the private key should not be in the server. a copy of the public key should be in the server. Do you have a copy of both these keys?