# ssh: connect to host (ip address) port 22: Permission denied

Tags: networking, server, permissions, ssh, windows

I just reinstalled the Ubuntu server OS on some devices and accidentally deleted the SSH keys in the %WINDOWS% folder and on the registry folder > Simon Tatham> then deleted it. Now, I can't access the central server. Is there any way to solve this? I've tried reinstalling the OS on the server, but it does nothing.[image]

Comment: You will likely need to generate a new key pair and copy the public key over to the server

Comment: How to generate the key?

Comment: Since you appear to be using Windows, ycan generate a key pair using puttygen and export the OpenSSH .pub key from that - see for example [How do I install an SSH private key generated by PuTTYgen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15378/how-do-i-install-an-ssh-private-key-generated-by-puttygen)